# Como serializar un timespan en API C# Core 3.x o superior

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, core

Tuve un problema en una API que tenia variables tipo time, me conecto a una base de datos con un campo Time y claro el JSON me devuelve algo así
"HoraTimeSpan": {
"ticks": 0,
"days": 0,
"hours": 0,
"milliseconds": 0,
"minutes": 0,
"seconds": 0,
"totalDays": 0,
"totalHours": 0,
"totalMilliseconds": 0,
"totalMinutes": 0,
"totalSeconds": 0
},

Cuando yo quiero asignarlo a un TimeSpan, o usarlo me despliaga el error de serialización al menos me paso en 3.x y 5 Core entonces ¿como puedo Corregir el problema?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta es sencilla y funciona para core 3.x y superior y puede servir también si necesitas serializar otros tipo de data como geo localización que también son estructuras tipo time. Este ejemplo lo hare con time

En la api hacemos una clase que permita manipular el time y hacerlo un string así que tendríamos una clase similar a esta:

```
namespace WebApiJWT.Models
{
     public class TimeSpanToStringConverter : JsonConverter<TimeSpan>
     {
          public override TimeSpan Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
          {
               var value = reader.GetString();
               return TimeSpan.Parse(value);
          }


          public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TimeSpan value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
          {
               writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
          }
     }
}
```

cuando se accesa al json para enviar la data el Json converter detecta que es un tipo TimeSpan y lo manipula tanto para lectura como escritura para que funcione en post y en get.

sencillo ahora solo bastara hacer la llamada desde la inyeccion de dependencias, eso lo hacemos en el startu en service

```
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
```

Ahi le decimos que cuando haga la serializacion utilice la clase de arriba, ¿como? de esta forma

```
           services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new TimeSpanToStringConverter()));
```

y ya esta.

Lo publico porque a mi me dio algunos dolores de cabeza y lo resolvi así
saludos